# Resource.axd files - Why so many and why so big?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

ASP.NET - I've managed to siginificantly reduce the number of .axd requests a page of mine is making by using the ajax ToolkitScriptManager control.

My question now is, why on earth is there SO MUCH JavaScript in those .axd files? I'm talking approx. ~1MB (un-gzipped) just to use a few Ajax controls on a page!

Is there anyway to make this leaner/smaller?

Is there some special way of configuring things that makes it smaller?

I'm guessing ASP.NET tries to only include the js it needs, so can I turn off anything to make the code less bulky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [compress](http://www.codeplex.com/MbCompression) the .axd files to make them smaller.